# Has the "Points of Light" setting grown beyond the Nentir Vale?

Tags: dnd-4e

In DnD 4.0, the Nentir Vale is the best known setting of the "Points of Light" scenarios. I don't know if there are any others, but the vale seems a bit small, and I figure it would get swamped with adventurers coming from all over to vanquish the kobolds. I don't have a DDI subscription, so I wouldn't know from there, and maps I've found describe only the Nentir Vale.

On the same vein, where would the Shadowfell and the Feywild be? Are there maps of the Points of Light world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Shadowfell and the Feywild are alternate planes that mirror the real world, rather than places in the real world.

There is a box set due out Summer 2011 called [Threats to the Nentir Vale](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/283640000)

So far there are a fair number of maps of vale on [google images](http://www.google.ca/images?hl=en&q=nentir+vale&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=univ&ei=zNgHTby5OcLEnAe215DmDQ&sa=X&oi=image_result_group&ct=title&resnum=2&sqi=2&ved=0CC8QsAQwAQ&biw=1280&bih=896), but other than the slight expansion of of the area to the south, in P1 King of the Trollhaunt Warrens, I don't know of anything else official.

edit:

As noted in answers to [Is there a world map for the core campaign setting for DnD 4e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/29528/is-there-a-world-map-for-the-core-campaign-setting-for-dnd-4e?lq=1), http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/Nerath_Map_HighRes.jpg is a map of Nerath, in which the Nentir Vale is found

Comment: One of the maps in your query, http://img80.imageshack.us/i/rhmapoy0.jpg/ , is of the Elsir vale. Interesting. There's also http://img222.imageshack.us/i/pointsofinterestgx5.jpg/ which seems to be a map of the world. Is that somewhat official?

Comment: Elsir vale is the setting for the Scales of War adventure path (and some pre 4e modules), which may or may not be in the Points of Light world (though it does share the Points of Light cosmology).

Comment: I've never seen the world map in any official source, so I can't confirm about it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't calling a plane 'the real world' a little confusing? Other planes are real, too. They are, however, different worlds.

Comment: @GMJoe If you can think of a better name for the default world, sure, but otherwise it's kind of hard to refer to distinctly. (I think WotC retired the name "Prime Material" with 3e.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Aw, 'Prime Material' isn't used any more? That's a pity. I guess maybe something like 'the home plane of most campaigns' will have to do.

Answer (score 4):

The current season of D&D Encounters (Keep on the Borderlands) is set in the Points of Light setting, along with the Chaos Scar, which it refers to. Other adventures (Treasure of the Silver Caves, etc.. and other Worldwide D&D Gameday adventures) are set in the same world. They've chosen a detail a small area at a time and build out approach rather than define the planet and then the individual continents and the nations, etc, "build down" approach.

Comment: Ok, but are there other areas detailed apart from the Nentir Vale? And where is the Chaos Scar? Or at least, is there a map of it?

Comment: In the front piece of each module, there are some maps- http://images.community.wizards.com/community.wizards.com/user/chaos_scar/a72d64f6e5c246152b88b818796b09ed.jpg?v=254400

Comment: (whoops, that closed out early).. but the Chaos Scar itself is in the same world. Supposedly this is between the Ogrefist Mountains and the Witchlight fens somewhere. There is no grand overview map, though.

Answer (score 3):

I don't own it myself, but there is the boardgame 'Conquest of Nerath' which is set in the same world as the Nentir Vale - it is even on the boardgame map. See [here](http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/338060000)

Comment: Nice find! There's a larger image of the map here: http://boardgamegeek.com/image/992420/dungeons-dragons-conquest-of-nerath-board-game . If you have a BGGeek/RPGGeek account you can see the large size that does indeed show the Nentir Vale. (Seeing various classic dungeons marked on it is somewhat amusing, aside.)