# Is there a world map for the core campaign setting for DnD 4e?

Tags: dnd-4e, campaign-settings

This question derives from: "[Is there a core campaign setting for DnD 4e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18249/is-there-a-core-campaign-setting-for-dnd-4e)".

The answers provided there were excellent and extremely helpful. Even more so when I saw that the board game Conquest of Nerath provides a map of continent.

Is a specific commercial version of Points of Light which includes a map? - if not a boxed campaign set than a perhaps a world/continent poster/map? I am hoping that there is such an entity rather than a collection of adventure-based settings.

Comment: Related (and has some maps): [this answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1204) to [Has the "Points of Light" setting grown beyond the Nentir Vale?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5234/1204)

Comment: After a bit of researching, I've decided that there really isn't any OFFICIAL map of a sort, which maybe somewhat obvious given the name 'Points of Light'! It would be nice, however, for Wizards ot Coast to release a sourcebook, or gazetteer as a starting point at least so DMs don't have to create everything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a [high-resolution map of the world around the Nentir Vale](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/Nerath_Map_HighRes.jpg) from the *Conquest of Nerath* board game. My understanding is that this board game is still canonical material for D&D 4e. I haven't yet found a source within the D&D 4e RPG franchise itself, however.

Having said that, there are adventures that take place outside the Nentir Vale, such as *Io'Vanthor: The Lost City of the Dragonborn* (Dragon 369) and *Nerathi Legends: The Knights of Rethmil* (Dragon 405) which describe geography consistent with this map.

(Note that this map could be printed at 300ppi and still be 13×11" or 33×28cm.)

Comment: @KhangNguyen - I've found it useful enough for my own campaigns, and I can show it to the players who give an appreciative *ooohhh* when they see where their adventure will take them :)